# How to use MINUS before WITH statement so as to select all rows from table 1 which are not in table 2 in Oracle SQL?

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a following query in Oracle SQL Developer:

```
query1:
with logg as
(select ID ...)
UNION
select ID from table2

query2:
select ID from table3
```

I would like to take all IDs from query 2 but remove those from query 2 which are in query 1, so for example:

results of query2

```
1, 2, 3
```

results of query1:

```
3, 4, 5
```

My expected result would be:

```
1 , 2  -- because they are in query 1 but not in query2.
```

I tried to use:

```
select ID from table3
minus
    (
        with logg as
        (select ID ...)
        UNION
        select ID from table2
    )
```

But it generates error: `cannot recognize input near 'MINUS' 'with' 'logg' in set operator` so as I mean it is no possible to use "MINUS" before "with".

What can I do ?

Comment: Are you sure you need to use `UNION` and not `UNION ALL` (before even getting to `MINUS`)? Also, `MINUS` will remove duplicates; do you need that? In particular, note that `UNION` rather than `UNION ALL` already does that (it de-duplicates); so if `UNION` is correct, then `MINUS` is definitely overkill - you will waste time unnecessarily.

Comment: mathguy, so what should I do in your opinion? because I do not undersand other answers, so maybe you have some idea how to modify my code? I need to remove duplicates of course

Answer (score 2):

You can compose multiple CTEs (Common Table Expressions) in a `WITH` clause, by separating them with commas.

For example:

```
with
logg as ( -- first CTE
  select ID ...
),
u as ( -- second CTE
  select * from logg
  UNION
  select ID from table2
)
-- now, the main query
select * from u
minus
select ID from table3
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this, without the "with" clause:

```
select ID from table3
minus
    (
        (select ID ...)
        UNION
        select ID from table2
    )
```

Comment: pmdba I have to use with clause

Answer (score 0):

Here is one way.

Suppose you could write the three queries like this:

1.

```
select id from ... where ...
```

2. 

```
select id from table2
```

3. 

```
select id from table3
```

Now, you want to get all the distinct id's from 1. and 2., which are not found in 3. Correct?

Then you can do something like this:

```
with
  logg (id) as (
    select id from ... where ... 
    UNION
    select id from table2
  )
select id
from   logg
where  id not in (select id from table3 where id is not null)
;
```

The `with` clause is what you have already (I think). To exclude the id's from the last query, you can use the `not in` condition.

Note the `where id is not null` clause in the subquery at the end. If `id` can't be `null`, you don't need it (obviously), but it won't hurt anyway. But if `id` can be `null`, you **must** include that `where` condition; this is where most beginners get the `not in` condition wrong.